# Amazon EC2 Boto: Filter out registered AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, boto

Let say I have 20 registered AMI. Is there a way to filter out **only** registered AMI using boto API command line?

```
E.g. 
get_all_volumes()
get_all_images()
get_all_instances()
get_all_snapshots(), etc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Filter the 'get_all_images()' by ownerID